# How to edit data using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna edit data using php, nip = identity employee. In my database nip (varchar). I can't edit using this code. but if I changed varchar into (int), this code can edit my data. How to  edit it using data type varchar...?

edit.php

```
<?php include "koneksi.php"; 
     mysql_query("UPDATE pegawai SET 
                  nip='$_POST[nip]',
                  nama='$_POST[nama]',
                  tempatlahir='$_POST[tempatlahir]',
                  tanggallahir='$_POST[tanggallahir]',
                  gender='$_POST[gender]',
                  alamat='$_POST[alamat]',
                  tanggalmasuk='$_POST[tanggalmasuk]',
                  jabatan='$_POST[jabatan]', 
                  foto='$_POST[foto]' 
                  WHERE nip = '$_POST[nip]'"
                );  
?>
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: mysql_query's are depricated, use PDO / mysqli instead. Watch out for SQL injections as well.

Comment: You need a space before `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php include "koneksi.php"; 
mysql_query("UPDATE pegawai SET nama='".$_POST['nama']."',
                               tempatlahir='".$_POST['tempatlahir']."',
tanggallahir='".$_POST['tanggallahir']."',
gender='".$_POST['gender']."', alamat='".$_POST
['alamat']."',tanggalmasuk='".$_POST['tanggalmasuk']."',jabatan='".$_POST['jabatan']."', foto='".$_POST['foto']."' WHERE nip = '".$_POST['nip']."'");  ?>
```

don't set nip in update.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE pegawai SET
nama='%s',tempatlahir='%s',tanggallahir='%s',gender='%s',alamat='%s',tanggalmasuk='%s',jabatan='%s', foto=''WHERE nip = '%s'",
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[nama])
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[tempatlahir])
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[tanggallahir])
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[gender])
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[alamat])
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[tanggalmasuk])
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[jabatan])
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[foto])
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[nip])
);

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

you can also use %u in the last parameter if nip is an integer. But please validate values before writting due to SQL Injections.

Comment: talking about sql injections, but letting him using the old `mysql_*` functions? lol :p @OP use [`mysqli_*` functions](http://php.net/mysqli)...

Comment: He is obviously only starting with php. probably doesn't even know  what is an sql injection. People need to see things work when they're starting.